# How to shutdown the computer when hitting the Power button?

Tags: shutdown, xfce, acpi

I have a **Xubuntu Lucid 10.04** computer plugged in to my TV. I use the command line to administrate it.

Right now when I hit the power button it just opens a Logout screen.

How can I set it up so that I can **shut it down by hitting the power button**?
I know it has something to do with acpi or acpid.

***I want answers to be command-line only** as I do not have any keyboard or mouse connected to that computer.*

---

### Edit:

Isn't there a way to modify the **default behavior** of the **xfce4 power manager when pushing the power button?**

Also instead of using the GUI to do so, can I do it by **creating/modifying a configuration file?**

jbowtie had an interesting answer but I cannot find the xfce4-power-manager.xml file. If someone knows where to find that file or how to create it, I would be interested.

Comment: Doesn't the logout screen time out automatically?

Comment: No, there is no time out.

Comment: Why can't you just edit `/etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh` as mentioned in my answer?

Comment: Would this file be replaced by an upgrade?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution. jbowtie put me on the right tracks. Kudos to him.

The problem was I **did not have any xfce4-power-manager.xml** file and I did not know exactly where to find the file and how to modify the file, but I found that I needed to copy the file from `/etc/xdg/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-power-manager.xml` and use `xfconf-query` to modify it properly.

The shutdown action for `/xfce4-power-manager/power-button-action` seemed to be **`4`**.

Here's what I did:

```
cp /etc/xdg/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-power-manager.xml $HOME/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml
DISPLAY=:0.0 xfconf-query -c xfce4-power-manager -p /xfce4-power-manager/power-button-action -s 4
```

Answer (score 5):

When you hit the power button, the script `/etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh` is called. So one option is to modify this script to just call the `shutdown` script, bypassing the power management daemon. This works across all distributions and environments that I know of.

Since you're using Xubuntu, you can however just change the setting 'power-switch-action' in `xfce4-power-manager.xml` to the shutdown action - the default value is the ask action.

Comment: I cannot find xfce4-power-manager.xml :(

Comment: I believe the usual location is $HOME/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-power-manager.xml

Answer (score 2):

You are indeed right about ACPI.

[This](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=175281#2) forum post is exactly what you're looking for.

It details the steps you need to take far better than I ever could explain it :)

Edit: Basically, the solution was to install `acpid`.

Comment: That page asks to sign in :( Isn't it possible to copy the contents here?