# Pressing the Power Button does not turn off the computer in Xubuntu

Tags: shutdown, xubuntu

I have installed Xubuntu 11.10 on a Compaq Presario P4. I am using it headlessly, to serve files. So the way I can turn off the box is by pressing the power button once. But it refuses to do it. Any advice?

I have configured in the SETTINGS MANAGER => POWER MANAGER so as to effect a shutdown on pressing the power button. I have also checked in the SETTINGS EDITOR that *property* "xfce4-power-manager => power-button-action" takes value of 4.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/460/how-to-shutdown-the-computer-when-hitting-the-power-button/559#559) post? The problem posed is similar to your question, and even has the same desktop environment and shutdown action.

Comment: Interestingly, I found the solution in [wiki section of Archlinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Shutdown_Pressing_Power_Button). And it worked like magic, except I feel the boot time has marginally increased

Comment: @tadatma please add that your solution as an answer, thanks. :)

Answer (score 5):

So instead of tadatma I am writing the solution from ([archlinux wiki first solution](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Shutdown_Pressing_Power_Button#First_solution) down here:

Create a file in /etc/acpi/events/ named powerbtn

```
gksudo gedit /etc/acpi/events/powerbtn
```

with following content:

```
# /etc/acpi/events/power
# This is called when the user presses the power button
event=button/power (PWR.||PBTN)
action=/sbin/poweroff
```

Restart acpid

```
sudo service acpid restart
```

This works for ubuntu 11.10 here.